# element toDefs and use with Snap.svg

Tags: svg, snap.svg

I don't know how to create an element in `<defs>` and `use` it in svg.

I try something like :

```
var s = Snap('#drawing');
var c1 = s.circle(ww / 2, wh / 2, 100).attr('id','c1').toDefs(); // in <defs>
```

and after

```
var cc = c1.use(); // in defs not in svg root
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should roughly work, I've just appended as well, here is an example...

```
var s = Snap(800,800);

var c1 = s.circle(100,100, 100).attr('id','c1').toDefs(); // in <defs>
var cc = s.append( c1.use() );
```

[test link](http://svg.dabbles.info/stackoverflowtest2.html)

Make sure you also have the latest snap ver 0.3.0 as I think there was a bug with defs in the older ones.

I also did a page a while back for this [here](http://svg.dabbles.info/snaptut-todefs) for Snap which may help a little to see it in use elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, I found this page after my question, by the way  I love http://svg.dabbles.info/ ! Nice work !

Comment: This works but now others `animate` disappear during animation (Chrome and Safari).

Comment: Maybe pop up a fiddle with an minimal example to highlight the issue.

Comment: I make something here : http://jsfiddle.net/rgWLT/169/ why opacity animation  is apply on the other element ?

Comment: You've mixed up your return values from append, this should work http://jsfiddle.net/rgWLT/171/   cache.use().appendTo(s).animate({opacity:0.1},4000)